# PHP Multi Dimensional Array's Value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok so I am making an API call using nusoap and I get an array retuned:

Here is a sample with values if the array has data:

```
$result['GetOrderListResult']['Status'] VALUE: - Success
$result['GetOrderListResult']['MassageCode'] VALUE: - 0 
$result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'] VALUE: -  array[1]
```

Her is the array is there is no data:

```
$result['GetOrderListResult']['Status'] VALUE: - Success
$result['GetOrderListResult']['MassageCode'] VALUE: - 0 
$result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'] VALUE: - ''
```

As you can see they are very similar apart from $result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'] which either contains an array or doesn't. And I need to check for this but I can't seem to.

```
if ($result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'] = "") {

        $numberofresults = 'True';
    } else {
        $numberofresults = 'False';
    }
```

This always returns False even when the value of $result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'] is "" which I copy & paste from from watching the variable in xDebug.

I'm sure there is an easier method to check this, but I cannot find anything that works but I am new to PHP so apologies if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You trying to assign(=) instead of compare(===).

   $result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'] = ""
2. Second you API could return array() or empty string? So it's better
   to double check

   ```
   if (is_array($result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData']) && count($result['GetOrderListResult']['ResultData'])) {
       $numberofresults = 'True';
   } else 
   {
       $numberofresults = 'False';
   }
   ```